# Android Studio: "Unsupported Hg version Some hg extensions [mercurial_keyring] are not found..."

Tags: android-studio, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-keyring

Android Studio gets on my nerves for a few days on my new PC with following message on start:

> "Unsupported Hg version Some hg extensions [mercurial_keyring] are not
> found or not supported by your hg version and will be ignored. Please,
> update your hgrc or Mercurial.ini file".

Everything works as it should (I only use "Annotate" in Studio). Why do they annoy me with this message?

I can disable keyring in TortoiseHg 5.0.2. Then Android Studio doesn't complain but without keyring I have to type in my password everytime I pull or push.

It's hard for me to ignore the message. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: I could swear I commented on here earlier... Strange... The problem still occurs. To better ignore it, I just leave Android Studio running and use Windows' hibernate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure now the problem comes from TortoiseHg. If I start a terminal from TortoiseHg Workbench "hg status" says "*** failed to import extension mercurial_keyring: No module named mercurial_keyring". I think it is wrong to use the global "mercurial.ini" if you don't provide global access to the extensions you can activate there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
Never trust a PC you didn't set up yourself from the start... The real problem was an additionale Mercurial installation. I realized it after updating TortoiseHg. The version number Android Studio displayed was still the old. I removed Mercurial and Python + Keyring and I am happy now. :)

**First attempt:**
I had to install Python and keyring and then update the mercurial.ini (mercurial_keyring = path to mercurial_keyring.py). Now Android Studio is crying because it thinks it cannot find Mercurial but it works. TortoiseHg seems to work like before.

I'm considering removing Mercurial plugin from Android Studio because it's not worth all the hassle. Integrated "Annotate" was nice, but if you're just annoyed with problems otherwise, you can do without it.